# Avl tree left rotation & left-right rotation usage confusion

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Assume we have the following structure:

```
        A
      /   \
     B     C
    / \
   D   E
```

Now, if C were to be removed,

```
     A
    /
   B
  / \
 D   E
```

At this point, every algorithm that I looked into makes the following check:

```
if (Balance-Factor(B)>=0) do **Left** rotation
else do **Left-Right** rotation;
```

But, why is it that this condition has to hold here? As in, if I were to do a Left-right rotation on the above tree, it seems as though I'd still be getting a balanced tree:

```
              E
             / \
            B   A
           /
          D
```

So, why is it that we have to only do a left rotation when even a right-left gives us a balanced tree for this scenario?

Comment: There is no single left rotation happening. That doesn't make sense since the tree needs rebalanced on the right side

Comment: what you refer to as right rotation is referred to as left by me.

Comment: Okay. Clockwise = right. Counterclockwise = left. That's how I learned it since that's the direction the nodes are moving

Answer (score 2):

The confusion stems from the namings they give to the rotations in most avl tutorials.

Namings: LL, RR, LR, RL

Cases     : L, R, LL, RR, LR, RL

A possible reason why most avl tutorials exclude the namings for the single rotations is because the single rotations can use the LL and RR codes. Basically the 2 single rotation codes are part of their corresponding  doubles.

In other words if the LL and RR codes are written properly, they can also be used for the single rotations.

In your example the case is a single rotation.
An L rotation which uses the LL code.
This is the reason you must not use the LR code.
Because the case is not even a double rotation to start with.

Proof:

```
      A
     / \
    B   G
   / \   \
  C   E   H
 /     \
D       F
```

Remove H:

```
      A
     / \
    B   G
   / \   
  C   E   
 /     \
D       F
```

With LR rotation:

```
      E
     / \
    B   A
   /   / \
  C   F   G
 /     
D           

Remains UnBalanced
```

With LL rotation:

```
      B
     / \
    C   A
   /   / \
  D   E   G
       \
        F

Is Balanced
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason only a "left" rotation is required is because the balance factor at node A is the first node to meet the rebalance criteria.

Think of each subtree as a weight on a scale, where the "weight" of these weights is the "height" of the subtree.

After deletion, B, E, and D are balanced.

The right subtree of A has "weight" 0, and the left subtree has "weight" 2.

This difference is greater than 1, towards the left subtree. Since the left subtree is balanced, only a single rotation at A is required towards the right subtree.

Comment: So, the only reason we choose L over LR is because LR involves 2 rotations while L involves only one?

Comment: Not necessarily. The reason only a single rotation is needed is because the subtree opposite the direction of rotation is balanced.